# Induced embedding of dual spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, and $X \stackrel{\Phi}{\hookrightarrow} Y$ is an embedding (continuous linear injection). Let $\Phi' : Y' \rightarrow X'$ be the induced map on the dual spaces.

If $\Phi(X)$ is closed, then by a Hahn-Banach argument, $\Phi'$ is surjective, i.e. a bounded linear functional on $\Phi(X)$ can be extended to $Y$.

**Question:** If $\Phi(X)$ is not closed, the Hahn-Banach argument breaks down, correct? If so, counter-example where $\Phi$ is not surjective?

Comment: Note that "Hahn" is not spelled "Hanh".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, let $X$ and $Y$ be $\ell^2$, the map $\Phi$ being $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\mapsto (x_n/n)_{n=1}^\infty$.

The induced $\Phi'$ is defined by the same formula (essentially the same map), and it's not surjective as, for example, $(1/n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is not in its range.

Comment: That's a compact self adjoint operator, with spectrum containing 0...is it an embedding?

Comment: @Michael, given that you only want a continuous injection, it certainly meets these criteria.

Comment: @TomekKania Right, 0 not in the point spectrum.